# Read name of the file which was taken as sys.argv[1] input

Tags: python, pandas, drag-and-drop

I have written a code to process the data of 3 excel files, and output a new file. The 3 files are dragged and dropped onto a batch file which opens ipython and then opens the .py file to run the code. The excel files which are dragged and dropped onto .bat file, are read as "sys.argv".

```
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]
file3 = sys.argv[3]
```

Then i read the files into pandas dataframes.

```
df1 = read_excel(file1,None)
df2 = read_excel(file2,None)
df3 = read_excel(file3,None)
```

The issue is that while dragging and dropping the files onto .bat file, i don't know which one will be read as file1/file2/file3.

I could read the column names within the dataframe to decide which one is which. But that may not work every time. The three files that I am dragging and dropping have unique names which will not change. I figured i could try and read the name of the file from sys.argv and then redirect them to the correct dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files have sufficiently different names you could try a simple string search using `in` like:

```
# a list containing your expected filenames
fileList = ["f1","f3","f2"]

dataframes = {filename: read_excel(file,None) for filename in fileList for file in sys.argv[1:] if filename in file}
```

giving you a dictionary with your filenames and dataframes of those files.